# coding style for = operator in knitr code chunk options brackets

Tags: r, coding-style, knitr

I've noticed that RStudio's auto-completion of knitr code chunk options defines the arguments with a `=` operator without any leading or trailing spaces. E.g.,

````
```{r echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, eval = TRUE, fig.show = 'hold'}
rnorm(100)
```
````

Hadley's [R code style guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html) calls for spaces around all infix operators.

So is there a different coding style for knitr code chunk options? I see a case for it if the goal is to minimize width of code chunk options definitions, I guess. But it would be nice if RStudio but spaces around the `=` if the no-space style is just a legacy.

Comment: Knitr's chunk options are based on Sweave which is in turn based on noweb. I'd imagine the lack of spaces relates to that history. Certainly all of the Sweave and knitr documentation uses no spaces around equals.

Comment: Styles are just styles. They are not rules. You can pick whatever style you like. There is nothing right or wrong to use spaces or not. I don't see a particular reason of no spaces (perhaps I didn't read the history of WEB/noweb carefully enough). I agree it is a valid question from the perspective of auto-completion, though.

Comment: Is there a way to change R code chunk option auto-completion preferences in RStudio?